# nginx proxy from subdomain to url

Tags: redirect, nginx, proxy

My config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 spdy;
    server_name subdomain.domain.com;
    add_header Alternate-Protocol  443:npn-spdy/3.1;

    include custom.d/ssl-redirect.conf;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/domain.com/domain_com-nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/domain.com/domain_com.key;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain_com.access.log geo;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/domain_com.error.log error;

    set $fpm_pool domain.com;
    root /home/domain.com/htdocs/domain_com/public;

    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://domain.com/mypath;
    }

    include custom.d/restrictions.conf;
    include custom.d/fpmstatus.conf;
}
```

I have https://domain.com/mypath URL.
And I want watch this when a call subdomain.domain.com
And when I call subdomain.domain.com/sompage. In may be throw https://domain.com/mypath/sompage

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a return, the best would be a 301 status code here:

`return 301 https://domain.com/mypath$request_uri;`

It may look like this in your code:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 spdy;
    server_name subdomain.domain.com;
    add_header Alternate-Protocol  443:npn-spdy/3.1;

    include custom.d/ssl-redirect.conf;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/domain.com/domain_com-nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/domain.com/domain_com.key;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain_com.access.log geo;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/domain_com.error.log error;

    set $fpm_pool domain.com;
    root /home/domain.com/htdocs/domain_com/public;

    index index.html index.php;

    return 301 https://domain.com/mypath$request_uri;

    include custom.d/restrictions.conf;
    include custom.d/fpmstatus.conf;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
I don't want redirect.
I want see url subdomain.doamin.com on browser

Comment: As far as I know, this behavior is not possible to produce as long as the content is not identical on both URLs.